# Getting error in creating hibernate connection in maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

```
/*Session session = BizeeHibernateConnection.getMySqlConnection();*/
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sf.openSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
List<Employee> listempdto = criteria.list();
System.out.println("================aaaaaa===============");
for (Employee employeeDTO : listempdto) {
    System.out.println("===============================================");
    System.out.println("ID : " + employeeDTO.getEmpid());
    System.out.println("USERNAME : " + employeeDTO.getUsername());
    System.out.println("FIRSTNAME : " + employeeDTO.getEmail());
    System.out.println("MIDDLENAME : " + employeeDTO.getMiddlename());
    System.out.println("lastname : " + employeeDTO.getLastname());
    System.out.println("phoneNo : " + employeeDTO.getPhoneno());

}
```

I am trying to create connection but I am getting the error below:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [InformationUser] in context with path [/leaveapp] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.generateDefaultReflectionManager(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:742)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:654)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at com.bizee.dao.InformationUser.doGet(InformationUser.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you post the hibernate xml file

Comment: is it hibernate.cfg.xml?? you are asking for

Comment: yes that is what i want to c

Comment: ya you can see now

Comment: in your pom.xml have you specified all the dependencies properly? From the exception thrown looks like `hibernate-annotations` is missing probably. Please check! (Also please post your hibernate configuration file in the question post itself, answer box are meant for answers)

Comment: i sent the whole pom .xml please check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Employee</property>
        <property name="connection.username">bizee</property>
        <property name="connection.password">mysql@BizEE</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <mapping class="com.bizee.bean.Employee" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Can you include some explanation/context for the code? Doing so makes it much more useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

In your maven file check if this dependency is there comment out the hibernate-annotations dependency there might be a conflict

```
<!--Hibernate-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
```

Comment: i sent the whole pom .xml please check it.

Comment: remove this   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>